# std:bad_alloc error in the program

Tags: stderr

I have this error in my program:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what(): std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anybody please explain what this means?

When i ran the program on my ubuntu machine it worked fine but on the interviewstreet platform it is giving this error.

Answer (score 1):

In general this means your machine has not enough memory... But yours problem description is too short to identify the problem source (provide some code?). About the problem appearing on one OS and not on another, I think it's compiler internal settings.